# How to verify ::after pseudo-element if exist in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a pre-defined field so you can only enter specific values and if you enter any other value (which is not mapped in database) then it throws error.
Now, I want to check for which values (from excel sheet), this field throws error but I am struggling to achieve this because the only things which changes in the DOM for invalid value is `::before`. If it is invalid `::before` will appear.
Example:

```
<label for="Broom" data-error="Please." class="active">::before</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I came across this problem, I could not see any way of doing this through the WebDriver locator strategy like XPATH, CSS etc. We can only use this via Javascript. Something like this:

```
public String errorCheck() {
    String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('label[for=\\'Broom\\']'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
    return content;
}
```

So, you can verify if it returns null for valid values. If you do more research around this, you will find you can do more validations as well i.e colour etc.
This is more from reference point of view.

Comment: similar answer shown here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/ZUi9cenA13o/rQ0KnSuYCgAJ